# How do I get the value of td using hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr>
 <td>#</td>
 <td>2009</td>
 <td><a class="delete_this">Click</a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to use jquery and get the text of 2nd (second) "td" when clicking the anchor. I want the "td" in the same tr as the anchor...

How do I do this?

So far I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".delete_this').click(function(){
   var myNUmber = $(this).parent()....///And this i should write the code to get the text for second td in tr where the anchor belongs to
 })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few ways:

```
$(this).parent().siblings("td:eq(1)").text()
```

If your looking for the cell before you can do it this way:

```
$(this).parent().prev().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.delete_this').closest('tr').children(':eq(1)') .text();`

1) Get the .delete_this A tag
2) Get the parent TR
3) Get the 2nd TD
4) Get the Text of the 2nd TD

Comment: delete_this is `<a>`. it has no siblings

Comment: Was in the middle of revising

Comment: use .closest instead of .parents

Comment: .children(':eq(1)') would be better also, but the siblings answer below is less work

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNUmber = $(this).parent().siblings().get(1).text();
```

Details are [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing)

Answer (score 1):

Your better adding just 1 click event by using .live rather than adding multiple click handlers, if you had a large table this will impact performance (think 100 separate bound events).

Also remember to prefix class selectors with nodeName if you can (here you are sure all delete_this are anchors)

```
 $('a.delete_this').live('click', function(){
   var myNUmber = $(this).parent().siblings().get(1).text();
 });
```